# Override the default pagination template of ui-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am using AngularJS to show pagination. I made some changes on the default pagination template. This is my HTML:

```
<ul uib-pagination ng-model="source_pagination.current" template-url="pagination.html" total-items="source_pagination.total_pages" items-per-page="1" max-size="source_pagination.max_items" class="pagination-sm" force-ellipses="true" direction-links="false" ng-change="source_page_changed()"></ul>
...
       <script id="pagination.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()}">
                    <a href ng-click="selectPage(1)" title="First Page">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()}">
                    <a href ng-click="selectPage(page - 1)" title="Previous Page">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index" ng-class="{active: page.active}">
                    <a href ng-click="selectPage(page.number)" ng-class="{highlight: ShouldHighlightPage(page.number)}">
                        {{page.text}}
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()}"><a href ng-click="selectPage(page + 1)" title="Next Page"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span></a></li>
                <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()}"><a href ng-click="$scope.changePage('last')" title="Last Page"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span> </a></li>
            </ul>
        </script>
```

I modified this section:

```
<li ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index" ng-class="{active: page.active}">
    <a href ng-click="selectPage(page.number)" ng-class="{highlight: ShouldHighlightPage(page.number)}">
                            {{page.text}}
    </a>
</li>
```

And added this class-condition `{highlight: ShouldHighlightPage(page.number)}`. This code should call the function `ShouldHighlightPage(pageNum)` which is located in the controller:

```
$scope.ShouldHighlightPage = function (pageNum)
{
    return true;
}
```

So all the pages should contain the class `highlight`. But this function is never called (checked by adding a breakpoint in the function). All the pages presented without the `highlight` class.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you confirm if the overridden template is used in the browser by inspecting the view

Comment: When changing the ng-class to `ng-class="{highlight: true}"` it's working. So, i sure that I see my custom made template.

Comment: It will be better if you can provide a minimal working example for this

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, got the issue here.

The `uib-pagination` directive creates an isolated scope. See it here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/2.1.3/src/pagination/pagination.js#L126

And from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-):

> #### Scope
>
> **{...} (an object hash)**: A new "isolate" scope is created for the
>   directive's element. The 'isolate' scope differs from normal scope in
>   that it does not prototypically inherit from its parent scope. This is
>   useful when creating reusable components, which should not
>   accidentally read or modify data in the parent scope.

That means, the method `ShouldHighlightPage` will not be available in the scope of your overridden template.

<strike>One immediate solution (**not recommended**, getting you a cleaner solution) is to register your method in `$rootScope`:</strike>

```
$rootScope.ShouldHighlightPage = function (pageNum)
{
    return true;
}
```

#### To fix this problem, add a custom directive:

```
myApp.directive('uibCustomPagination', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'uibPagination',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, uibPaginationCtrl) {
            uibPaginationCtrl.ShouldHighlightPage = function (pageNum) {
                return true;
            };
        }
    }
});
```

This directive is basically injecting your method to the controller of `uib-pagination` directive so that it can be available in your template.

Now, just apply `uib-custom-pagination` directive to your `ul` element:

```
<ul uib-pagination uib-custom-pagination ng-model="source_pagination.current"
    template-url="pagination.html" total-items="source_pagination.total_pages"
    items-per-page="1" max-size="source_pagination.max_items" class="pagination-sm"
    force-ellipses="true" direction-links="false" ng-change="source_page_changed()"></ul>
```

Comment: Good point. I just updated my code according to yours. For some reason, the function `ShouldHighlightPage` still never being called. Can you estimate why?

Comment: Not sure, it will be better if you can provide me a working example for this